# How to get user details using Google Sign In method in a fragment JAVA class of BottomNavigationView?

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview, googlesigninaccount

This is my Fragment Class. Its a part of BottomNavigationView:

```
package com.healthapp.instacare;

        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
        import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
        import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

        import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
        import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{
    GoogleSignInAccount acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getActivity());

    TextView name= (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView surname= (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.surname);
    TextView id= (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.id);
    TextView email= (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.email);
    ImageView profimg = (ImageView)getView().findViewById(R.id.profimg);


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getinfo();
    }

    private void getinfo() {
        if (acct != null) {
            String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
            String personFamilyName = acct.getFamilyName();
            String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
            String personId = acct.getId();
            Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();

            name.setText(personName);
            surname.setText(personFamilyName);
            id.setText(personId);
            email.setText(personEmail);
            profimg.setImageURI(personPhoto);
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile,container,false);
    }

}
```

This is the method that Google provided using Documentation:

```
GoogleSignInAccount acct = 
GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getActivity());
if (acct != null) {
    String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
    String personGivenName = acct.getGivenName();
    String personFamilyName = acct.getFamilyName();
    String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
    String personId = acct.getId();
    Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
}
```

How can I implement it in a fragment? I am new to android studio coding.

I have already created some TextViews and ImageViews in a `.xml` file for the fragment, and I was hoping to replace those texts and image URL with the ones from Google's account info and display it.

I tried the above code , but it's crashing probably because of NullPointerException.

Comment: Your question might get more traction, if you posted your attempt at making this a fragment ([creating fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating)) and then asked a question regarding a specific issue you were running into.

Comment: Okay, I'll add it.